# HashMap me muestra elementos duplicados java

Tags: java, string, loops, arraylist

Mi pregunta es **como puedo mostrar solo los registros que tengo en mi hashmap sin repetirlos?** Ej: Tengo un `arraylist<String>` cargado con datos, tambien tengo un archivo de texto cargado con datos dentro.

- Contenido de archivo **.txt**:

**25,Argentina**

**45,SAN SALVADOR**

**32,VENEZUELA.**

- Contenido `arraylist`

**25_ARGENTINA**

**45_SAN SALVADOR**

Como verán si yo cargo un map de mi archivo de texto y lo comparo las claves(Dígitos numéricos de dos cifras) con lo que tengo en mi `arraylist` **debería** de mostrarme los países coincidentes a esas claves, en este caso seria **ARGENTINA** y **SAN SALVADOR**

Pero en vez de eso me sale:

**País: ARGENTINA**

**País: ARGENTINA**

**País: ARGENTINA**

**País: null**

**País: SAN SALVADOR**

**País: SAN SALVADOR**

Tengo un método que lee el archivo de texto, lo carga en un String, luego cargo lo almacenado en el String en un hashmap, antes recorro el arraylist y obtengo los dígitos de dos cifras y lo almaceno en **keyArray**:

```
 String keyArray;

public void leer(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        Map<String, String> mapaCodigosArchivo = new HashMap();

        //Recorremos el arrayList
            for (String nombreArchivo : arrayList) {
                String[] separador = nombreArchivo.split("_");
                String codPaises = separador[0];
                keyArray = codPaises;
            } 

        try {
            // Abrimos el archivo con la ruta especificada.
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(new File("Paises.txt"));
            // Creamos el objeto de entrada
            DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            // Creamos el Buffer de Lectura
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entrada));
            String contenido;
            // Leer el archivo linea por linea
            while ((contenido = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] separador = contenido.split(",");
                mapaCodigosArchivo.put(separador[0], separador[1]);
               //Imprimimos los resultados que coinciden con la clave de dos digitos.
                System.out.println("Sucursal: " + mapaCodigosArchivo.get(keyArray));
            }
            // Cerramos el archivo
            entrada.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { //Catch de excepciones
            System.err.println("Ocurrio un error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

E investigado pero no doy con la respuesta correcta, espero me puedan ayudar. Desde ya gracias.

Comment: Al parecer estás algo perdido en tu código. Si he entendido bien, recibes un array en parámetro, y de ese array intentas obtener las llaves numéricas. 1º. Aquí almacenas sólo una llave: `keyArray = codPaises;` ya que `keyArray` a pesar de su nombre está declarado como String más arriba. 2º. Cuando `keyArray` sea en realidad un array conteniendo las llaves numéricas a buscar, necesitas implementar algo diferente de esto: `System.out.println("Sucursal: " + mapaCodigosArchivo.get(keyArray));` para buscar **todas** las llaves coincidentes, pues necesitarás iterar **también** sobre `keyArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si usas JDK 7+ puedes probar este código. Si usas una versión anterior, habría que variar la forma de leer el mapa y hacer las comparaciones.

Una buena opción es el uso de [`keySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--), el cual:

> Devuelve una vista de conjunto de las llaves contenidas en un mapa. El
>   conjunto está respaldado por el mapa, por lo que los cambios en el
>   mapa se reflejan en el conjunto, y viceversa. Si el mapa se modifica
>   mientras está en curso una iteración sobre el conjunto (excepto a
>   través de la operación de eliminación propia del iterador), los
>   resultados de la iteración no están definidos. El conjunto admite la
>   eliminación de elementos, que elimina la correlación correspondiente
>   del mapa, a través de las operaciones `Iterator.remove`, `Set.remove`,
>   `removeAll`, `retainAll` y `clear`. No admite las operaciones `add` o
>   `addAll`.

#### Código:

```
String [] keyArray; //Lo definimos como array

public void leer(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        Map<String, String> mapaCodigosArchivo = new HashMap();

        try {
            // Abrimos el archivo con la ruta especificada.
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(new File("Paises.txt"));
            // Creamos el objeto de entrada
            DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            // Creamos el Buffer de Lectura
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entrada));
            String contenido;
            // Leer el archivo linea por linea
            while ((contenido = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] separador = contenido.split(",");
                mapaCodigosArchivo.put(separador[0], separador[1]);
               //Imprimimos los resultados que coinciden con la clave de dos digitos.
                System.out.println("Sucursal: " + mapaCodigosArchivo.get(keyArray));
            }


            //Recorremos el arrayList
            for (String nombreArchivo : arrayList) {
                String[] separador = nombreArchivo.split("_");
                String codPaises = separador[0];
                keyArray.add(codPaises); //Agregamos al array
            } 

            for(String key : mapaCodigosArchivo.keySet()) {
                if(keyArray.contains(key)) {
                    System.out.println("Sucursal: " + mapaCodigosArchivo.get(key));
                }
            }

            // Cerramos el archivo
            entrada.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { //Catch de excepciones
            System.err.println("Ocurrio un error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

---

#### DEMO COMPLETO SIMULANDO LOS DATOS

Dado que estás leyendo un archivo de texto es difícil simular los datos. He creado de forma artificial un array que simularía los datos extraídos de tu archivo de texto.

El código funciona a la perfección. Creo que si lo adaptas en tu contexto podrás llegar a una solución definitiva del problema.

#### `Código` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/RALB54710)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Collections; 
import java.util.HashMap;
class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        /*Creamos array de prueba*/
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.add("25_ARGENTINA");
        arrayList.add("45_SAN SALVADOR");

        leer(arrayList);

    }


    public static void leer(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        List<String> keyArray= new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String, String> mapaCodigosArchivo = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String, String> mapaFinal = new HashMap<String, String>();

        System.out.println("Array con los códigos: "+arrayList);


        for (String nombreArchivo : arrayList) {
                String[] separador = nombreArchivo.split("_");
                String codPaises = separador[0];
                keyArray.add(codPaises); //Agregamos al array
        } 

        System.out.println("Array con los códigos extraidos de arrayList: "+keyArray);


        /*Creamos array de prueba, ponemos repetidos a propósito*/
        ArrayList<String> arrayTexto = new ArrayList<String>();
            arrayTexto.add("25,Argentina");
            arrayTexto.add("45,SAN SALVADOR");
            arrayTexto.add("32,VENEZUELA");
            arrayTexto.add("25,ARGENTINA");
            arrayTexto.add("45,SAN SALVADOR");
            arrayTexto.add("32,VENEZUELA");
            arrayTexto.add("25,Argentina");

        System.out.println("Array simulado archivo de texto: "+arrayTexto);

        for (String paises : arrayTexto) {
                String[] separador = paises.split(",");
                String codPaises = separador[0];
                mapaCodigosArchivo.put(separador[0], separador[1]);
        }       

        System.out.println("Mapa códigos archivo: "+mapaCodigosArchivo);
        System.out.println("Mapa códigos archivo keySet: "+mapaCodigosArchivo.keySet());

        for(String key : mapaCodigosArchivo.keySet()) {
                if(keyArray.contains(key)) {
                    System.out.println("Sucursal: " + mapaCodigosArchivo.get(key));
                }
            }
    }
}
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
Array con los códigos: [25_ARGENTINA, 45_SAN SALVADOR]
Array con los códigos extraidos de arrayList: [25, 45]
Array simulado archivo de texto: [25,Argentina, 45,SAN SALVADOR, 32,VENEZUELA, 25,ARGENTINA, 45,SAN SALVADOR, 32,VENEZUELA, 25,Argentina]
Mapa códigos archivo: {45=SAN SALVADOR, 25=Argentina, 32=VENEZUELA}
Mapa códigos archivo keySet: [45, 25, 32]

---Esta es la salida esperada:

Sucursal: SAN SALVADOR
Sucursal: Argentina
```

Comment: Estimado colega, e probado su codigo y me da **null** si implemento esta parte del código `mapaCodigosArchivo.get(keyArray)` pero si cambio a `mapaCodigosArchivo.get(key)` la cosa cambia, creo que eso habrás querido poner, igualmente tu código me ayudo mucho a entender algunas cuestiones, gracias. La salida de datos que tengo ahora es **ARGENTINA ARGENTINA SAN SALVADOR** estimo que es porque tengo elementos repetidos en mi hashmap, pero tu código es un 90% correcto, lo marco como respuesta, gracias.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya ayudado @GerardoFerreyra He actualizado la respuesta, poniendo al final un ejemplo completo simulando los datos. He introducido algunos cambios, más que nada en `keyArray`, declarado esta vez como `List`. En el ejemplo obtengo los resultados esperados. Es decir, Argentina no aparece dos veces. Efectivamente me había equivocado poniendo `keyArray` en el `get` del `Map`. Saludos.